# Shouldn't block operations always be interruptible?

Tags: c++, ipc, deadlock, thread-synchronization, boost-interprocess

In my opinion, all block operations should provide some mechanism to interrupt the wait and have the thread return cleanly, just like the [alertable wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069(v=vs.85).aspx#alertablewaitfunctions) operations in Windows API. However, other than Windows API, such a feature is hardly seen. I don't know why.

Just imagine what could happen if a block operation does not provide such a mechanism. The [`message_queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue_t.html) class in Boost.Interprocess is such an example. Its `send()` and `receive()` methods are blocking. That means the process with a blocked thread will not have total control over itself. Unless some external factors come into play, such a process could not even choose to exit cleanly, for there is practically no way to force the blocked thread out of its wait state. In addition to that, without such a feature, there is no clean way to solve a deadlock that has already happened and has been detected. Despite these, I have seen a lot of blocking operations designed without such a feature. Why is this? Am I just getting something wrong?

Another example would be [`std::mutex::lock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock) in C++11. But since it is process-wide, and the *external factors* are still within the process's control, the issue is not that serious as a machine-wide blocking mechanism would be. But wouldn't it be much better to just provide a withdraw method? I know about `std::condition_variable`. I just think that every blocking operation should be interruptible, even at the price of some performance degradation.

Comment: I think this question might be more appropriate on [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you think you would ever need to "force the blocked thread out of its wait state", then using a blocking wait is perhaps a coding error.  On the other hand, I have implemented debug commands and send a no-op command to the blocked task (as a short-cut to resume testing).  Not part of normal code operation.

Comment: If you have a deadlock, you already have an implementation error / logic error.  IMHO - better to spend your time finding the cause.

Comment: @NathanOliver when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: The blocking operation is interruptible in Python. For example mutex.acquire()